# Echo statement is echoing non-text

Tags: php, python, html, echo, bottle

I am running a simple bottle server that I set up on python:

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file

@route('/')
def home():
    return static_file("home.html", root='.')

@route("/<fileName>")
def respond(fileName):
    return static_file("%s" % fileName, root='.')

run(host="localhost", port=8080, reloader=True)
```

When I run this code, it works perfectly and I can add any filename to the localhost url(http://localhost:8080) and the code will return the file specified if it is there. So I can type "https://localhost:8080/home.html" and it will return my home.html file that displays: Welcome to my home page!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However, whenever I try to embed a PHP echo statement, it always adds on what is after the text, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<h1>Welcome!</h1>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Returns: `Welcome!"; ?>`

This also happens when I try to use a pure PHP file with the php extension:

```
<?php
    echo "<h1>Welcome!</h1>";
?>
```

Is there something I need to add to my server code or is there something wrong with my PHP installation? (I know that the PHP code is right)

Comment: You expect __python__ server will process __php__?

Comment: Well, yes. I bought a PHP book, and in the examples it just hosts the files in the same way that the python code does. However, the examples in the book use a third party executable to host (Which I do not want to use, I really want to use python)

Comment: Well, just give up. Python server won't process php. That is apache2 server's scope.

Comment: Using __python__ for processing __php__ is like making a cat bark. You can spend a lot of time on training, but it's faster to get a dog.

Comment: Does php not just run as a folder though? So can't I just return a php file and it will process itself on the host computer?

Comment: @Andbeav you obviously have a lot to learn. No, php - like all server-side technologies - has to be executed (in this case by a php interpreter) on the server. What the browser gets is only the result generated by the PHP (or Python or whatever) code on the server.

Comment: I know, I am very new to PHP. Is there any way to execute the php from the python code? I don't really care how long it takes to train the cat to bark xD

Comment: Why not just run the built in php server?

Comment: There's a built in php server? If you know that it will be able to return php and html files please post an answer! :D

Comment: Why don't you just run php? `php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t /path/to/your/php/files/`

Comment: @ronrothmanℝℝ, Thanks for the feedback! I had already done that a few hours after Neil Masters suggested it. However, your comment does give a solution, so if you post an answer, I will happily mark it is the answer.

Comment: Thanks; converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply run php instead of Python?

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t /path/to/your/php/files/
```

Comment: Thanks! I created a python executable to run the php commands to host the server and it's working perfectly! I can't quite figure out how to serve files on the empty url though... (http://localhost:8080/)